# How to find the first index of the words?

Tags: java, string, substring

I use the following code

```
 String fulltext = "I would like to create some text and i dont know what creater34r3, ";
    String subtext = "create";

    int ind = -1;
            do {
                ind = fulltext.indexOf(subtext, ind + subtext.length());

            } while (ind != -1);
```

As a result, I find the first index of the words:

`create creater34r3`

But I need to find the first index only of the words **`create`**

How to do it? help

Comment: Did you just delete your question and re-posted it? Why?

Comment: easier for me to to present a thought at first

Comment: Do you want to find "created"? "create."? "create" (at the end of the string)?

Comment: As an example, when you write in a notebook and smeared it - you pulled a piece?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement to find whole words in a string, if they're present, then how about this:

```
    String fulltext = "I would like to create some text and i dont know what creater34r3, ";
    String subtext = "create";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + ")\\b");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(fulltext);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

The output would be `create`

But it occurs to me that you need the actual index - if so you can add this to the while block:

```
      int start = matcher.start();
      int end = matcher.end();
```

Comment: Thank you to help me. I want to ask you, i have `subtext = "create s";` how do I get `subtext = "create some"; or subtext = "create";`  ??

Comment: @MaxUsanin - so you want the index of either "create" or "create some"?  Is that right?

Comment: no, it is not relevant to the post. I have some substring for example "create s" or "create som" or "create so" if "create some" - it's alright, I need to substring consisted of whole words

Comment: How about this? Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}+)");

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138738/how-to-get-the-whole-words-use-substring