# how to get the whole words use substring?

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have string `String fulltext = "I would like to create some text and i dont know what creater34r3, ";`

and i have substring  `String subtext = "create s";` or `"create som"` or `"create so"`..

**how to get the whole words for `subtext` ?** (in this case  "create some" or "create")

`Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}+)");` - not work =(

Comment: I am not sure what your are trying to achieve. Do you want to find the rest of the word at the end of the subtext if any?

Comment: @Ingo Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}+)\\b") - not work

Comment: **How**???????? How does "it" not work? Do you think we have crystal balls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, but you should use `Matcher.find()` (which finds the first occurrence of the regex) instead of `Matcher.matches()` (which tests the regexp against the whole string).

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}*)").matcher(fulltext);
System.out.println(m.find());
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Prints

```
true
create some
```

Edit: as Sean Landsman pointed, it should be `\\p{Alnum}*` (because subtext may occur at the end of the string, and would not be matched if a `+` quantifier were used).

Comment: `group(0)` returns the complete pattern, while `group(1)` returns the first capture group (between parenthesis). In this case there is no difference since `\\b` is only an empty marker, but if you replace it by `\\s*` then the substring is captured as `group(1)`.

Answer (score 3):

How about?

```
Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}*)");
```

This will return `create some` for the 3 subtexts above

If not, can you please say what your expected output is for `create s`, `create som` and `create so`?

Comment: String fulltext = "I would like to create some text and i dont know what creater34r3, ";
  String subtext = "create so";
     Pattern pattern_2 =  Pattern.compile("\\b(" + subtext + "\\p{Alnum}*)");
     Matcher matcher_2 = pattern_2.matcher(fulltext);
     while (matcher_2.find()) {
      Matcher i = matcher_2;
     } right?

Comment: @MaxUsanin in your while loop, matcher_2.group(), matcher_2.start() and matcher_2.end() will give you the matched string, and the start and end index - is that what you're after?

Comment: I understood, Sorry but you are a little late I pointed the other answer, thank you for helping me

Comment: @MaxUsanin No problem - the main thing is your got it working!